# Sharing via Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Google Plus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, google-plus, sharing

I would like a section where users can share a certain link on different social media platforms from our app. I have the twitter link working properly but Facebook, LinkedIn, and G+ are only sharing the URL and not a custom message.

Twitter

```
a.twitter-share-button href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=sharethiscom&text=BlahBlahBlah&url=http://#{Figs.ms.url}/#{@app.uuid}" target="_blank"
```

Facebook

```
a.fb-share-button href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://#{Figs.ms.url}/#{@app.uuid}&t=BlahBlahBlah target="_blank"
```

LinkedIn

```
a.linkedin-share-button href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http://#{Figs.ms.url}/#{@app.uuid}&summary=BlahBlahBlah” target="_blank"
```

G+

```
a.gplus-share-button href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://#{Figs.ms.url}/#{@app.uuid}" target="_blank"
```

I’d like the custom message to be BlahBlahBlah so when they click any of these links it would fill out the custom message and include the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current page url is (request.original_url )

1. For Facebook you can do the following, For more details check the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) for more details:

> %a.fb-share-button{:href =>
>   "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=#{APP_ID}&display=popup&href=#{URL_TO_SHARE}&redirect_uri=#{request.original_url}",
>   role: "menuitem", tabindex: "-1", target: "_blank"}

You can customize the page title, description, previewed photo by addting them to the URL_TO_SHARE meta tags. Check [Open Graph Object Meta Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects) for more details.

```
%meta{:content => "1234567890", :property => "fb:app_id"}/
%meta{:content => "http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614", :property => "og:url"}/
%meta{:content => "Chocolate Pecan Pie", :property => "og:title"}/
%meta{:content => "https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/851565_496755187057665_544240989_n.jpg", :property => "og:image"}/
```

2. For Linkedin

> %a{:href =>
>   "http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=#{URL_TO_SHARE}&title=#{TILTE}&summary=#{SUMMARY}&source=www.YOUR_DOMAIN.com",
>   role: "menuitem", tabindex: "-1", target: "_blank"}

Comment: is it required that I have an App Id to just have a custom share button on my app that links to another page they've created? Seems very excessive. Also, when I try to add the summary to the linkedin url it's not being filled in.

Comment: For facebook you don't have to pass the app_id, but its good to keep for the app analytics. For linkedin the summary should be 256 characters maximum, check their [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin)

Answer (score 1):

**Twitter:** *[Official Twitter Share Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview)*

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={url}&text={title}&via={user_id}&hashtags={hash_tags}
```

**Facebook:** *[Official Facebook Dialog Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)* / [*Official Facebook Sharer Documentation*](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/)

If you have an API key...

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id={app_id}&display={page_type}&href={url}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}
```

And if you don't...

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

**LinkedIn:** *[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)*

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

**Google+:** *[Official Google+ Share Documentation](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/9195133?hl=en#:~:text=On%20April%202nd%2C%20your%20Google%2B,pages%20will%20also%20be%20deleted.)*

```
N/A : Service disabled.
```